# How do I dynamincally rename EC2 windows hosts in an Autoscaling group using Terraform Userdata?

Tags: powershell, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am passing the userdata through terraform which changes the windows EC2 hostname. This userdata configuration is part of an autoscaling group launch configuration. For each windows EC2 instance which spins up in this Autoscaling group, I need to assign a different hostname. Like adding a number at the end of specified hostname - Eg. hostnamedev (hostnamedev01, hostnamedev02, ...). Thank you

*init.ps1*

```
#<<=======<<=======||Environment Variables from User Data||=========>>========>>
$newHostname = "${hostname}"

#<<===========================||Hostname Change||=============================>>
function UpdateHostname {
  param (
    [Parameter (Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]$newHostname
  )

  If ($newHostname -ne $env:COMPUTERNAME) {
    
    Try {
      Rename-Computer -NewName $newHostname -Restart -ErrorAction Stop
    }  
    Catch {
      $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
      Write-Output "Rename failed: $ErrorMessage"
    }
  }
  else {
    Write-Output "The Host Name is Updated already"
  }
  Write-Output "The Host Name is $env:COMPUTERNAME"
}

UpdateHostname -newhostname $newHostname
```

*userdata.tf*

```
data "template_file" "user_data" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/init.ps1")}"
  vars = {
    hostname     = "hostnamedev"
  }
}
```

*module.tf*

```
module my_module {
  #...
  user_data                          = data.template_file.user_data.rendered
}
```

*ec2.tf*

```
resource aws_launch_configuration launch_config {
  image_id                    = var.ami_id
  instance_type               = var.instance_type
  iam_instance_profile        = var.iam_instance_profile_name
  key_name                    = var.key_name
  user_data                   = var.user_data
}

resource aws_autoscaling_group asg {
  launch_configuration      = aws_launch_configuration.launch_config.name
  max_size                  = var.max_node
  min_size                  = var.min_node
  force_delete              = true

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not move the `data "template_file"` under the module?  ... that way you can put a count on it like you probably have for the EC2 instances

Comment: I kind of understand what you are saying, it would be really helpful if you could put that in a few lines of code, Thanks

Comment: can you provide the code of your module where the instances are created...

Comment: Please check the updated question, Thanks

Comment: ouch... It's part of an `autoscaling_group` ... sooo my idea of using the index on a count would not apply ... does the number needs to be sequential? Maybe append the IP address